# VSCode extension Installation Dependency activation order

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I have a VSCode extension which has an installationDependency in the package.json:

```
"extensionDependencies": [
    "publisher.packagename"
 ]
```

this works well - it runs the activation event for the dependency before the one I have written as you would expect:

```
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {...
```

however - I would like my extension to first reset an environment variable before the dependency activates. Is it possible to determine (in my case reverse) the order of activation events or is there some event before activation I can use?