# Can a VSCode extension activate method be async?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Can a VSCode extension activate method be async?

It seems to work.

I can't find anything that says not to do this.

None of the extension samples that I checked have async activate methods.

The code in [VSCode extension Installation Dependency activation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002146/vscode-extension-installation-dependency-activation-order) does do it and the author says it works.

Is there any reason not to do this?

The reason I hope that I *can* have an async activate method is my extension activates on "*" because printing applies to all files. Some people are getting high extension CPU warnings. The official advice is to bundle with webpack but it seems to me this just turns the problem into an up-front cost.

Personally I never experience slow loading but that may be due to use of an SSD which would ameliorate the cost of lots of small files.

Comment: I don't know the definitive answer but I'm guessing yes. Some extension examples do it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/github-authentication-sample/src/extension.ts    https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/source-control-sample/src/extension.ts

Comment: converting a function to async only affects what it returns. It will return a promise.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I don't know is whether the framework uses activate as a void function (probably) or _expects_ it to block (uncertain).

Comment: @boocs - I missed that one in my random sampling. Thanks. Write it up as an answer.

Comment: Why would you vote this down? It's a real question with a definitive answer. What kind of scum would make it harder to find for those who come after?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some extension examples do it. Here are two for example:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/github-authentication-sample/src/extension.ts

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/source-control-sample/src/extension.ts

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

vscode [calls the `activate` function using apply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e440a9b/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostExtensionService.ts#L564) and then [uses Promise.resolve](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e440a9b/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostExtensionService.ts#L568) to create a Promise from the `activate` function's return value.

So if `activate` is async it returns its Promise. If `activate` is not async, a Promise is created that resolves to its return value.

In either case the return value becomes a `Promise<IExtensionAPI>` ie: a promise containing the [extension's api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e440a9bb7dfbe8a0b76fc76894fcf189b8d2e6b8/src/vs/workbench/api/common/extHostExtensionActivator.ts#L26).